# How can I prove this Bessel function relation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, gamma-function, bessel-functions

> Prove
>   $$J_{s \pm 1}(z) = \frac{s}{z}J_s(z) \mp J_s'(z)$$
>   from
>   $$J_s(z) = \sum^\infty_{j=0} \frac{(-1)^j}{\Gamma(j+1)\Gamma(j+s+1)}\Big(\frac{z}{2}\Big)^{2j+s}$$

I proved $J_{s - 1}(z) = \frac{s}{z}J_s(z) + J_s'(z)$ easily but never succeeded for another case. I tried to write terms out directly or change the index from the proved one and do manipulation, but both attempts failed. Please help.

Comment: hope the answer helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$J_s(z) = \sum^\infty_{j=0} \frac{(-1)^j}{\Gamma(j+1)\Gamma(j+s+1)}\Big(\frac{z}{2}\Big)^{2j+s}$$

$$\implies J_{s+1}(z) = \sum^\infty_{j=0} \frac{(-1)^j}{\Gamma(j+1)\Gamma(j+s+2)}\Big(\frac{z}{2}\Big)^{2j+s+1}$$

$$\implies J_{s+1}(z) = \sum^\infty_{j=0} \frac{(-1)^j}{(j+s+1)\Gamma(j+1)\Gamma(j+s+1)}\Big(\frac{z}{2}\Big)^{2j+s+1}$$

and

$$J'_s(z) = \sum^\infty_{j=0} \frac{(-1)^j\times(2j+s)}{2\times \Gamma(j+1)\Gamma(j+s+1)}\Big(\frac{z}{2}\Big)^{2j+s-1}$$

$$\implies J'_s(z) = \sum^\infty_{j=0} \frac{(-1)^j\times(2j+s)}{z\times\Gamma(j+1)\Gamma(j+s+1)}\Big(\frac{z}{2}\Big)^{2j+s}$$

$$\implies J'_s(z) = \sum^\infty_{j=0} \frac{(-1)^j\times(2j)}{z\times\Gamma(j+1)\Gamma(j+s+1)}\Big(\frac{z}{2}\Big)^{2j+s}+\sum^\infty_{j=0} \frac{(-1)^j\times(s)}{z\times\Gamma(j+1)\Gamma(j+s+1)}\Big(\frac{z}{2}\Big)^{2j+s}$$

$$\implies J'_s(z) = \sum^\infty_{j=0} \frac{(-1)^j\times(2j)}{z\times\Gamma(j+1)\Gamma(j+s+1)}\Big(\frac{z}{2}\Big)^{2j+s}+\dfrac {s}{z}\times J_s(z)$$

$$\implies J'_s(z) = \sum^\infty_{j=0} \frac{(-1)^j*(2j)}{z\times j(j+s)\times\Gamma(j)\Gamma(j+s)}\Big(\frac{z}{2}\Big)^{2j+s}+\dfrac {s}{z}\times J_s(z)$$
$$\implies J'_s(z) = \sum^\infty_{j=0} \frac{(-1)^j}{(j+s)\times\Gamma(j)\Gamma(j+s)}\Big(\frac{z}{2}\Big)^{2j+s-1}+\dfrac {s}{z}\times J_s(z)$$

Replace $j$ with $j+1$ in the first summation, and noting that $\Gamma (0)\to \infty$, you get:
$$\implies J'_s(z) =- \sum^\infty_{j=0} \frac{(-1)^j}{(j+s+1)\times \Gamma(j+1)\Gamma(j+s+1)}\Big(\frac{z}{2}\Big)^{2j+s+1}+\dfrac {s}{z}\times J_s(z)$$

$$\implies J_{s + 1}(z) = \frac{s}{z}J_s(z) - J_s'(z)$$

Comment: Impressive! Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are welcome :-)